# Having trouble referencing my Tkinter Toplevel instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, toplevel

I am having trouble referencing a Toplevel created within a frame.

I'm still relatively new to python so any help would be great.

The problem occurs when the searchList(Entry) tries to import data into the contactMenu(Toplevel) instance.

```
from Tkinter import *

emailList = ['one.two@gmail.com','two.three@gmail.com','five.six@gmail.com','seven.eight@gmail.com']


class searchList(Entry):

    def set_completion_list(self, completion_list):
        self._completion_list = completion_list
        self._hits = []
        self._hit_index = 0
        self.position = 0
        self.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.handle_keyrelease)

    def autocomplete(self, delta=0):
        """autocomplete the Entry, delta may be 0/1/-1 to cycle through possible hits"""
        if delta: # need to delete selection otherwise we would fix the current position
            self.delete(self.position, END)
        else: # set position to end so selection starts where textentry ended
            self.position = len(self.get())
        # collect hits
        _hits = []
        _hits.sort(key=str.lower)
        for element in self._completion_list:
            if element.startswith(self.get().lower()):
                _hits.append(element)
        # if we have a new hit list, keep this in mind
        if _hits != self._hits:
            self._hit_index = 0
            self._hits=_hits
        # only allow cycling if we are in a known hit list
        if _hits == self._hits and self._hits:
            self._hit_index = (self._hit_index + delta) % len(self._hits)
        # now finally perform the auto completion
        if self._hits:
            contactsMenu.displayField.delete(0, END)
            #contacts.displayField.insert(0,self._hits)
            self.select_range(self.position,END)
            for items in range(0, len(self._hits)):
                contactsMenu.displayField.insert(0,self._hits[items])

    def handle_keyrelease(self, event):
        """event handler for the keyrelease event on this widget"""
        if event.keysym == "BackSpace":
            contactsMenu.displayField.delete(self.index(INSERT), END)
            self.position = self.index(END)
            self.autocomplete()
        if event.keysym == "Left":
            if self.position < self.index(END): # delete the selection
                contactsMenu.displayField.delete(self.position, END)
                self.autocomplete()
            else:
                self.position = self.position-1 # delete one character
                contactsMenu.displayField.delete(self.position, END)
                self.autocomplete()
        if event.keysym == "Right":
            self.position = self.index(END) # go to end (no selection)
        if event.keysym == "Down":
            self.autocomplete(1) # cycle to next hit
        if event.keysym == "Up":
            self.autocomplete(-1) # cycle to previous hit
        # perform normal autocomplete if event is a single key or an umlaut
        if len(event.keysym) == 1:
            self.autocomplete()


class mainApp(object):

    def __init__(self, master, content):

        self.master = master

        master.title("EMailer")

        bgColour = "white"

        #Setting up Frames

        #Main Frame
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.master, padx = 10, pady = 10, bg = bgColour)
        self.mainFrame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

        self.toButton = Button(self.mainFrame, command=self.startContacts, borderwidth = 1, padx = 8, pady = 5, text = "To..", bg = bgColour)
        self.toButton.pack(padx = 5, pady = 2)


    def startContacts(self):

        contactsMenu = Contacts(Toplevel(self.master), emailList)


class Contacts:

    def __init__(self, master, content):

        self.master = master

        master.title('Contacts')
        master.geometry('600x600+600+200')

        self.bgColour = "white"

        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.master, padx=10, pady=10, bg=self.bgColour)
        self.mainFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self._content = content

        # Top and Bottom Frames
        self.topFrame = Frame(self.mainFrame, bg='blue')
        self.topFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=False, anchor=NE)

        self.midFrame = Frame(self.mainFrame, bg='red')
        self.midFrame.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.botFrame = Frame(self.mainFrame, bg='green')
        self.botFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=10, fill=X, expand=False, anchor=SW)

        self.topLeftFrame = Frame(self.topFrame, bg='pink', width=440, height=35)
        self.topLeftFrame.propagate(0)
        self.topLeftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.topRightFrame = Frame(self.topFrame, bg='orange')
        self.topRightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.botLeftFrame = Frame(self.botFrame, bg='pink')
        self.botLeftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.botRightFrame = Frame(self.botFrame, bg='orange')
        self.botRightFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.searchBar = searchList(self.topLeftFrame)
        self.searchBar.set_completion_list(emailList)
        self.searchBar.pack(anchor=SE, padx = 10, pady = 8)

        self.searchButton = Button(self.topRightFrame, text="Search", padx = 30, pady = 4)
        self.searchButton.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

        # Insert text field of some sort
        self.scrollBar = Scrollbar(self.midFrame)
        self.scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.displayField = Listbox(self.midFrame, selectmode=MULTIPLE, bg="purple", yscrollcommand=self.scrollBar.set,font='Calibri', height=23, width=92)
        for items in self._content:
            self.displayField.insert(END, str(items))
        self.displayField.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=8)

        self.scrollBar.config(command=self.displayField.yview)

        self.selectButton = Button(self.botLeftFrame, command=self.callBack, text="Select", padx = 30, pady = 4)
        self.selectButton.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.cancelButton = Button(self.botRightFrame, command=self.closeWindow, text="Cancel", padx = 30, pady = 4)
        self.cancelButton.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.searchBar.focus_set()

    def closeWindow(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def callBack(self):
        pass

if __name__ =='__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = mainApp(root, emailList)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The words you chose don't make sense. You don't "import" data into a toplevel. Can you be more specific? Do you get an error? If so, what error? If not, how is the behavior you get different from the behavior you expect?

Comment: The first problem i get is within the autocomplete function, when it runs it inserts/deletes the results into a Listbox(displayField) which is found within the Contacts class.

NameError: global name 'contactsMenu' is not defined

contactMenu is defined when it is created from the button on the first window
    
    def startContacts(self):

        contactsMenu = Contacts(Toplevel(self.master), emailList)